# Using Query Builder in Codeigniter - How to properly alias?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have built the following query using query builder in codeigniter 3.x

```
        $this->db->select('
            categories.*,
            posts.id,
            posts.category_id,
            posts.user_id,
            posts.updated_user_id,
            posts.title,
            posts.slug,
            posts.body,
            posts.post_image,
            year(posts.created_timestamp) as year, 
            month(posts.created_timestamp) as month
        ');
```

The above produces the error, Unknown column 'year' in 'where clause'.  I have dumped the sql but simply cannot figure out why SQL cannot recognize year and month?

```
SELECT 
    `categories`.*, 
    `posts`.`id`, 
    `posts`.`category_id`, 
    `posts`.`user_id`, 
    `posts`.`updated_user_id`, 
    `posts`.`title`, 
    `posts`.`slug`, 
    `posts`.`body`, 
    `posts`.`post_image`, 
     year(posts.created_timestamp) as year, 
     month(posts.created_timestamp) as month 
     FROM `posts` 
     JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`category_id` 
     WHERE 
        `year` = '2019' 
     AND `month` = '1' 
     LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not an codeigniter  issue that is  how MySQL works year is not a field name (please avoid that kind of field name)
its a function and selecting or calling function is not same as defining it  so you have to put where clause  same way you have selected it  .

```
SELECT 
    `categories`.*, 
    `posts`.`id`, 
    `posts`.`category_id`, 
    `posts`.`user_id`, 
    `posts`.`updated_user_id`, 
    `posts`.`title`, 
    `posts`.`slug`, 
    `posts`.`body`, 
    `posts`.`post_image`, 
     year(posts.created_timestamp) as year, 
     month(posts.created_timestamp) as month 
     FROM `posts` 
     JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`id` = `posts`.`category_id` 
     WHERE 
        year(posts.created_timestamp) = '2019' 
     AND month(posts.created_timestamp) = '1' 
     LIMIT 5
```